# Undefined field when trying to create a condition for a custom constraint in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to create a custom constraint in GCP for the resource type Firewall (let's say I'm trying to implement the `FIREWALL_RULE_LOGGING_DISABLED` rule from the table [here](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/concepts-vulnerabilities-findings))

In the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/firewalls) I see the `Firewall` object has a `logConfig` field

However, the GUI complains the field is undefined

(If I go to [Custom Constraint Supported Services](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/custom-constraint-supported-services) and then [Firewall](https://cloud.google.com/firewall/docs/custom-constraints#supported-resources) I see `logConfig` doesn't appear to be a supported field)

[image: screenshot of error message showing 'undefined field logConfig']

What am I doing wrong? How can I then implement the `FIREWALL_RULE_LOGGING_DISABLED` rule?

Answer (score 1):

Because it was not supported, don't be confused with the [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/firewalls) that you shared. The link you shared is a configuration for an application or if by chance a Vm instance that supports a firewall using json. It is not applicable in the IAM environment.

Regarding firewall rule logging, it is disabled by default based on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/how-to-remediate-security-health-analytics-findings#firewall_rule_logging_disabled) this link will tell more about the “Firewall rules logging is disabled”.

For custom constraint under IAM these are the only [supported resources](https://cloud.google.com/firewall/docs/custom-constraints#supported-resources) the same link that you also shared.